# To use Siebel web service with C# ASP.NET applications(Web Services)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, siebel

Since I am a newbie to Siebel web services,Could anyone please give me information about how to invoke a Siebel web service(inbound and Outbound) in C# .NET application and using them with web service or windows services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple steps are:

1. Select the mode (inbound or outbound)
2. Configure the business logic in Workflow or Business Service
3. Configure the Web service in application (go to site map > web services)
4. In application, make sure configure the port url correctly
5. From the application, generate the WSDL
6. From .Net or Java or any consumer call the WS using the WSDL contract.

For details please refer [the Bookshelf](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/CRMWeb/CRMWeb_Overview.html).

Remember if logic is ready then consuming or exposing a business logic is required 10 minutes configuration. :)

Answer (score 0):

The idea about web services is that it's not vendor specific. Thus, a Siebel Web Service (inbound) is just like any other web service. There are millions of examples on calling web services in C#.

But, there are some helpful stuff in the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/EAI2/EAI2_WebServices12.html) ;) I this doc, specifically you can use a **Mobile Web Client** to respond to WS calls. Like this there is no need for a Siebel Server install and jumping through the loops to setup an [inbound web service](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/EAI2/EAI2_WebServices7.html) and enabling the **EAI Object Manager**(s).